# ActionBarStyleGenerator - how to use it?

Tags: android, styles, android-actionbar

So, I have tried to use [ActionBarStyleGenerator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/#name=example&compat=holo&theme=light&actionbarstyle=solid&texture=0&hairline=0&neutralPressed=1&backColor=E4E4E4%2C100&secondaryColor=D6D6D6%2C100&tabColor=33B5E5%2C100&tertiaryColor=F2F2F2%2C100&accentColor=33B5E5%2C100&cabBackColor=FFFFFF%2C100&cabHighlightColor=33B5E5%2C100). It generates all style.xml file and all its left is to somehow set it for the action bar. The problem is that I use support libraries (app support 2.1 android) and I have issues with setting action bar style.xml to it.

Have you ever tried using this tool. If so, can you help me out and explain how to set style for the action bar?

Answer (score 2):

> The problem is that I use support libraries (app support 2.1 android) and I have issues with setting action bar style.xml to it.

You can set it to generate the resources for `ActionBarCompat` or `ActionBarSherlock` as well.

Since you are using the support library you have to choose `AppCompat`:

[image]

Comment: Okay, but maybe you have some sort of example of how to correctly set that style for actionbar in styles.xml. I have looked for explanations and tried to set it myself, yet no luck...

Comment: Just copy everything in the res folder that you extract from the downloaded zip to the res folder in your project. Simple as that.

Comment: It doesn't work like that, and I don't think it should. You need to point to custom style that you have just added. But how to do so?

Comment: yes I did `android:theme="@style/Theme.custom_style`. But I get exception `java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity`. I have generated style by selecting AppCompat as you said. What could be the issue?

Comment: Does the generated theme inherit from Theme.AppCompat?

Comment: Yes, it does inherit from AppCompat.